# Telerik kendo mobile: Pull to load more

Tags: user-interface, mobile, kendo-ui, telerik, pull-to-refresh

i load the data with pull-to-refresh new. But i want to show second pull-to-refresh-button on below and with it the show more data. 
Is this possible?

Thanks

```
<div data-role="view" data-init="viewInit" data-model="viewModel">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-template="foo-template" data-bind="source: dataSource"></ul>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="foo-template">
    #: name # - #: modified #
</script>

<script>
    var i = 0;
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
      dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({ name: "record" + i, modified: +new Date() })
    });

    var viewInit = function (e) {
        var scroller = e.view.scroller;
        scroller.setOptions({
              pullToRefresh: true,
              pull: function () {
                  loadMore();
                  scroller.pullHandled();
            }
        });
    }

    var loadMore = function () {
        var max = i + 5;
        var data = [];
        for (; i < max; i++) {
            viewModel.dataSource.add({ name: "record" + i, modified: +new Date() });
        }
    }
    new kendo.mobile.Application();
</script>
```

http://prntscr.com/79j3pk